# Text carousel on timer with fade in, fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have some text fade out, change, and fade back in at regular intervals and automatically (ie, no button).

I cannot get this code to synchronize setInterval with the fading. I've tried fadeToggle as well as a combination of fadeIn and fadeOut together.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div id="changeText">Zero</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    var text = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
    var counter = 0;
    var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");

    setInterval(change, 3000);
    function change() {

    $("#changeText").fadeToggle(3000);

     elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
        counter++;
        if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }

    }
    </script>
```

PS I am agnostic about the solution. If this can be done more elegantly in CSS (which I've used for fading but not transition), please let me know.

Comment: Is it supposed to fade out then increment or fade out and then back in as another number. What exactly are you expecting to happen?

Comment: why not use transitions by adding a class, changing the text and then transition back in by removing the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try utilizing `.fadeTo()` , [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operator

```js
var text = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");

function change() {
  $(elem).fadeTo(3000, 0, function() {
    this.innerHTML = text[counter];
    counter = ++counter % text.length;
    $(this).fadeTo(3000, 1, change)
  })
}

change()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="changeText">Zero</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Comment: What if I have <div class="changeText">Zero</div> appearing multiple times in the page (and am using getElementsByClassName) -- how can I get the changes to be in sync (ie, change to one, two, three simultaneously)?

Comment: @zadrozny Tried using `.each()` ? Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Haven't. Please do. Don't know much JS.

Comment: @zadrozny Not have full `html` here containing _"<div class="changeText">Zero</div> appearing multiple times in the page"_ , here . Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net including `html` , `js` tried ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a million ways to skin a cat. If you want to do fadeToggle, I wouldn't also use setInterval, because they will be called at the same time and cancel each other out.

One thing to keep in mind is that fadeToggle will effect more than just the opacity and turns the objects display off once it is hidden, and that could effect your layout.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div id="changeText">Zero</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    var text = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
    var counter = 0;
    var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");

    $(document).ready(function(){ change()});
    function change() {

    $("#changeText").fadeToggle(3000, 'swing', function(){
      if($("#changeText").css("display") == "none")
      {
     elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
        counter++;
        if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }

      }
      change();
    });

    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this compares performance wise. This implementation has no dependencies.

```
(function() {
  var STEP  = 0.1;
  var x = 0;
  var text  = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
  var element = document.querySelector('#changeText');

  if(!element) { return; }
  element.innerText = text[0];
  requestAnimationFrame(change);

  function change() {
    var y = Math.sin( x );
    var opacity = (y + 1) / 2;

    x += STEP;
    element.style.opacity = opacity;

    if(y <= -0.99 && Math.sin(x) > -0.99) {
      var txtIdx = text.indexOf(element.innerText);
      if(txtIdx === text.length - 1) {
        element.innerText = text[0];
      } else {
        element.innerText = text[++txtIdx];
      }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(change);
  }
})()
```